# iOS 10 - Swift 3 - Trying to test Facebook Authentication

Tags: swift3, firebase-authentication, ios10, facebook-authentication

Please do not mark as duplicate. This is for iOS 10 and Swift 3. I have tried everything in the other questions on this site.

I am testing the button in my app that allows the user to log in by using facebook. I double checked everything in the tutorial that I was following and I still get the same error when I test the button in the simulator. The console shows ...

canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Here is the code I used in the View Controller where the user signs in:

```
@IBAction func facebookBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to authenticate with Facebook - \(error)")
        } else if result?.isCancelled == true {
            print("User cancelled Facebook authentication")
        } else {
            print("Successfully authenticated with Facebook")
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)
            self.firebaseAuth(credential)
        }
    }
}

func firebaseAuth(_ credential: FIRAuthCredential) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to authenticate with Firebase - \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully authenticated with Firebase")

        }
    })
}
```

}

There are no errors in my code, everything is properly setup through facebook and firebase. It works fine for the teacher in the tutorial. I am trying to print: "Successfully authenticated with Facebook" and "Successfully authenticated with Firebase"

The tutorial is the Devslopes Social App from their course on Udemy. Has anyone here had this same problem and been able to resolve it? Any help is appreciated.